# Pipe, map and observable fail to retrieve json

Tags: angular

In an angular project I'm desperately trying to get a usable response from an API call.
 I tried it in many ways:

This is what the API is responding (tested in browser and postman):

```
{
  "cols": [
    [
      "Open", 
      "High", 
      "Low", 
      "Close", 
      "volume"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried it with http method in a service component with observables:

```
  getDfColumns(): Observable<DfColumns[]>{

    return this.http.get<DfColumns[]>(this.URLColumns);

  }
```

and the main component where I call the function with the get method:

```
DfCols!:any;

  getCols() {

    this.DfCols = this.indicatorService.getDfColumns().pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
    console.log(this.DfCols)
  }
```

returns an empty observable: `Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}`

I also tried in the main component:

```
this.DfCols =  this.indicatorService.getDfColumns().subscribe(columns => {this.DfCols = columns;})
```

The result is an `undefined`

..and finally http method in a service component without an observable (I still don't get the purpose of observables in these simple API calls):

```
  getDfColumns(){
  
    return this.http.get(this.URLColumns);

  }
```

Nothing helps! What is wrong with that? How do I get the proper response?

Update Code:

main component (getCols() is trigger by button):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'
import { CallFunctionService } from 'src/app/services/call-function.service';
import {LoadIndicatorParamsService} from 'src/app/services/load-indicator-params.service';
//import { RestServiceDfinit } from 'src/app/services/rest-df-init.service';
import { DfIndicatorService } from 'src/app/services/rest-df-indicator.service';
import { DfColumns } from 'src/app/interface/df-indicator';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formgroup-indicator',
  templateUrl: './formgroup-indicator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formgroup-indicator.component.scss']
})
export class FormgroupIndicatorComponent implements OnInit {


  toggleAdd: boolean = false;
  toggleDelete: boolean = true;
  
  IndicatorGroup = new FormGroup({
    IndType: new FormControl(''),
    Ind: new FormControl(''),
    IndPeriod: new FormControl(''),
    IndOpt1: new FormControl(''),
    IndOpt2: new FormControl(''),
  });

  DfCols!:any;


  constructor(private callDfFunction: CallFunctionService, private IndicatorParams: LoadIndicatorParamsService, private indicatorService: DfIndicatorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  getCols() {

    this.DfCols = this.indicatorService.getDfColumns().pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));

    this.DfCols.subscribe((data:any) => console.log(data));
    console.log(this.DfCols)
  }

}
```

service component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import { DfIndicatorRoot, DfColumns } from '../interface/df-indicator';
import {LoadIndicatorParamsService} from './load-indicator-params.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DfIndicatorService {


  URLColumns: string = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/df_columns/";



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

  
  }
  getDfColumns(): Observable<DfColumns[]>{

    return this.http.get<DfColumns[]>(this.URLColumns);
    //console.log(this.DfColumns)
  }
```

The interface:

```
export interface DfIndicatorRoot {
    ind: string;
    params: DfIndicatorParams[];
  }
  
  export interface DfIndicatorParams {
    ind_type: string;
    period: number;
    optional_param_1: number;
    optional_param_2: number;
  }


  export interface DfColumns { cols:object}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read an observable, you have to subscribe to it to get the value, like this

```
getCols() {
  this.indicatorService.getDfColumns().pipe(
    tap(() => console.log(response)),
    // I am not sure about this line it could be response.body just log it and check
    map((response: any) => response),
    take(1),
  ).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    this.DfCols = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: I get: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')`

Comment: Can you share your whole code please, the indicatorService and the main component

Comment: Ok I've uploaded it

Comment: where do you call getCols()?

Comment: I updated my answer, if this doesnt work, this means that your get request is not succeding

Comment: I assume `take(1)`is not part of the solution, right? I get this: `ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function`. The get request is succeeding because if I console log the entire request I receive the appropriate response

Comment: `take(1)` is part of the solution, because if you don't do it, everytime your get emits, and if it emits multiple times, you might have your value updated without you wanting it

Comment: However, `ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function` you don't need to do .json(), I assume you come from a react world, you just have to use response as it is

Comment: Yep, I kicked out `json()` and also `take(1)` because it throws errors and I won't have problems with unwanted emits. So now it works! Thank you!!

Comment: I really suggest using take(1), if you subscribe inside a function, you will have problems when your app grows cuz you will have memory leaks, better solve it now, I can help with that

Comment: What error does it throw ?